# Using AJAX to load another working button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

So I am starting to use AJAX and jQuery in my current project and I am running into an issue here.

I have set up this test site where I want to load some content through ajax and a php file if I press a button.

For Example:

Button1 is pressed and the php file returns "Button1 pressed".

I want to make some sort of menu with it where I would need a "Back"-Button.

So through the php file I echo another button with the back value but when I click it, nothing happens.

Sorry if my topic is some sort of a duplicate, I did not know what to look for.

Here are my two files:

> button.html

```
<div id="result">
<button class="TestButton" value="test1">test1</button>
<button class="TestButton" value="test2">test2</button>
<button class="TestButton" value="test3">test3</button>
<button class="TestButton" value="test4">test4</button>
<button class="TestButton" value="test5">test5</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(".TestButton").click(function() {
    var buttonValue = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'buttonValue.php',
      data: { value: buttonValue },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
      }
    });
  });    
</script>
```

**buttonValue.php**

```
<?php

    $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : "empty";

    if($value == "empty") echo "Kein Button gewählt!";
    if($value == "back") echo "hello";

    if($value == "test1"){
      echo '<button class="TestButton" value="back">Zurück</button>';  // pressing first button to echo back-button
    }           

    ?>
```

Comment: this isn't working because the eventHandler (`$().click(..`) is set _before_ the second button get's inserted into the DOM.

Comment: you _could_ set another/new eventHandler after inserting that button. _BUT_ this is a weird way to do what you wanna achieve.

Comment: @Jeff So I would need to "echo" the ajax request with the button?

Comment: @Jeff So in which way would you solve it? I currently cannot think of another solution :/

Comment: better would be to have the 'back-button' already in the dom, but hidden/disabled. Then in `success` show the back-button.

Comment: @Jeff The Thing is, that I later want to add more buttons as a "sub-menu". The first buttons shown on page loadup will be more like product categories and clicking them will bring up their respective products. Clicking on the product will add it to the shopping cart.

Comment: ah, ok. Then go with @SmitReval 's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are manipulating the DOM dynamically you need to bind event on each elements that are added after DOM render.

```
$(document).on("click",".TestButton",function() {
    var buttonValue = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'buttonValue.php',
      data: { value: buttonValue },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Use this script to bind click event on each button added before or after DOM render.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark the answer as approved if it has solved your issue. Thanks. :) @TheEarthkin

Comment: Ohh didn't knew that. Alright thanks again. :) @TheEarthkin